# GtkFrame not drawing a box around its child

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I'm seeing a  difference between GTK versions 2.x and 3.x. In GTK 3, the `GtkFrame` widget doesn't draw a box around its child, as it did in version 2.x. Does anyone know the reason for this?

Comment: so, what is your q? why GtkFrame draw a box around its child? it's an ornament

Comment: Yes, I can't see these when I compile with gtk3, but compiling with gtk2 the surrounded box appear

Comment: for all i know there won't be any difference in any version of Gtk o about GtkFrame. Maybe you should try to change your default gtk theme to Raleigh and see if it's drawn or not.Further than that, if it fails you, drop the Frame, its pretty useless anyway since every Gtk..View has its own 'frame' surrounds it, GtkToolbar has also style context that can modify its appearance different than the rest of the widgets. But if you really curious, report the bug to gnome.org

Answer (score 0):

The default style for frames in GTK 3 is an invisible border. If you want to see the borders, add some CSS like so:

```
.frame {
    border: 10px solid red;
}
```

You can do this with a [`GtkCssProvider`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCssProvider.html), here is a rough example with no error-checking:

```
GtkCssProvider *provider = gtk_css_provider_new();
gtk_css_provider_load_from_data(provider, ".frame{border:10px solid red;}", -1, NULL);
gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen(gdk_screen_get_default(), provider,
    GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);
```

Comment: I appreciate the advice and I apologize for my limited knowledge on this subject, but reading the reference documentation gtk+, I can not find where it mentions how to change the attribute of the widget frame as visible. I would be grateful if you could to indicate me how to do this, if it were not a very complicated issue.

Comment: I tried the piece of code that sent me, and this makes the magic. Now the frame box appears even in compiling gtk3. I am amazed at all there is in this programming gtk gui's. I have the feeling that this far exceeds my modest knowledge of programming in C, born with borland c in ms-windows, and now as enthusiastic student linux, gnu-gcc and gnome, in my time of retirement. Thank you so much for your respectful attention and time spent.

Comment: @user3692294 can you please post a snippet of how did you draw border for widgets in gtk2? I'm trying it in gtk2 and its not drawing the border. Thanks.